# Random BSODs on Windows 7 boot. Can't find a valid reason

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, bsod, minidumps

I bought and assembled a new PC:

```
Asus m4a785td-v EVO
AMD x4 620
OCZ Black Edition 2x 2GB
WD 500GB SATA
```

Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit fresh install BSOD on boot. Formatted, reinstalled, BSOD on install. Ran memtest -> no errors. Ran Windows 7 install in safe mode. Installed, random BSOD on Windows 7 startup, even in safe mode. Updated BIOS. Ran the Windows 7 memtest (no error), booted after some tries and ran [Prime95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime95) blend test for 12 hours straight with no errors at all!
When the PC has booted, Windows 7 runs as smooth as possible, I've been playing STALKER for 4 hours straight with not a single hiccup.

Using Blue Screen View I can see that every BSOD involves:

```
ntoskrnl.exe
```

[Here are the dumps](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1606950/bsod.txt)

Ran sfc/scannow as admin:

> Windows Resource Protection found
>   corrupt file but was unable to fix
>   some of them.

What's going on?

Comment: On board video?

Comment: Yes, on board video.

Answer (score 2):

A BSOD is most likely to be either a hardware problem (e.g. unreliable memory) or a driver.

Submitting a bug report to MS (you should be prompted for this after the reboot) will tell you if it can be matched to a know issue (or unambiguously linked to a specific drive).

(You can do the same analysis, without the know issues database, with `windbg` and `analyze -v`.)

If that fails you need to divide and conquer, by running hardware diagnostics to eliminate some hardware problems. Also deleting devices with 3rd party drivers (and don't allow Windows to en-enable them might allow you to find a driver issue.